# Xamarin CrossDownloadManager - cannot open downloaded file

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I got a problem with opening downloaded files using Xamarin CrossDownloadManager.
My code is everything like in this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcbm6R4e8jQ

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
        public void Downloaded()
    {
        CrossDownloadManager.Current.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new System.Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file =>
        {
            //here .doc just for test - full filename is 30.doc, will be changed. 
            string fileName = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.Url).Path.Split('/').Last() + ".doc";
            return Path.Combine(ApplicationContext.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName);
        });
        }
```

And download method:

```
    public async Task<Stream> DownloadDocument(int id)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var downloadManager = CrossDownloadManager.Current;            
            var file = downloadManager.CreateDownloadFile(url);
            downloadManager.Start(file, true);
        });

        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that I cannot open file when i go to ,,Downloads" folder. It has proper file size but it act's like it's missing file type. Message says ,,Cannot open file".
If I check it's details there is Type: File instead of Type: Document Word.
IF I COPY this file to other folder, I can open it there without any problems.
Got no idea where can be the problem :/

Comment: I test his code in the video, I got the file name called `Unsuccessful`. Do you get the same name?

Comment: i get name "30" because this is my parameter in uri. It's why i add ".doc" to filename in mainActivity  (just for test, will be implemented later). Ofcourse i am downloading .doc file.

Comment: If you donwload file name is correctly, You can change another path to download the file.

Comment: I have  to stay with downloads folder. It looks like file is saved with proper name, just without its extension. If I move this file to another folder and move it back to Downloads I can open it... I just can't open it directly after download.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I was downloading files from Azure Blob Storage.

In case someone else has this same problem, the cause of this error was that the Content Type was not set when I initially uploaded the files to the container.  Once I assigned a correct Content Type (MIME), the downloaded files have the correct type.

If you're making use of the new Azure blob client SDK, see this link for guidance on setting the correct Content Type when uploading to the container:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/9823